# Powershell - Simplified Logging - Is this legid?

Tags: powershell, logging, pipeline, outputstream

Today I have dealt with logging in PowerShell as well as with the different streams and the pipeline. Unfortunately, none of these solutions really met my needs.

My requirements are:

- I need to output information from PowerShell to a file log.
- The file log has a predefined structure. So it's not enough to just redirect all streams to the file.
- I want to use mainly standard PowerShell functions such as Write-Error, Write-Warning, Write-Verbose.
- The overhead in the code through logging should be minimal.

I have now developed the following idea:

1. When calling a function from my script, all streams are piped to a logging function.
2. This function separates the debug, verbose, warning and error objects from the resulting object.
3. The resulting object is released back into the pipeline.

Here is my solution:

```
function Split-Streams {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $InputStream
    )
    process{
        switch($InputStream.GetType())
        {
            'System.Management.Automation.DebugRecord' { 
                                                         # Do whatever you want, like formatting an writing to a file. 
                                                         Write-Host $InputStream -ForegroundColor Gray
                                                       }
            'System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord' {
                                                         Write-Host $InputStream -ForegroundColor Red
                                                         Write-Host ('Error function: {0}' -f $InputStream[0].InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name) -ForegroundColor Red
                                                       }
            'System.Management.Automation.VerboseRecord' { Write-Host $InputStream -ForegroundColor Cyan }
            'System.Management.Automation.WarningRecord' { Write-Host $InputStream -ForegroundColor Yellow }
            default { return $InputStream }
        }
    }
}

function Write-Messages
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()   
    Write-Debug "Debug message"
    Write-Output "Output message"
    Write-Verbose "Verbose message"
    Write-Warning "Warning message"
    Write-Error "Error message"
}

$Test2 = Write-Messages -Verbose -Debug *>&1 | Split-Streams

Write-Host $Test2 -ForegroundColor White
```

So now my question:
Is there something wrong with my solution? Have I missed any problems?

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: Please post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: I'll do that when my cooldown for new question expires.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/224400/powershell-simplified-logging-is-this-legid

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should've been posted on codereview (as it has been now)